# Encrypted home dir suddenly failing to mount on boot

Tags: linux, linux-mint, boot, home, ecryptfs

After an update and a reboot, my ecryptfs home directory in Linux is failing to decrypt and mount on boot. It caused a bit of a panic, as Mint seemed entirely reinstalled from scratch (but the contents of `/usr/` are still there and the wifi is still configured, so that's how I know it was just the home dir that was affected. `/home/username/` was just brand new.

The `/home/.ecryptfs/username/` directory was still there (with subdirectories `.ecryptfs` and `.Private`), and the amount of free space on the disk hadn't increased. I managed to mount and decrypt it from a live USB, and backed up the unencrypted data to external storage. Any tips on restoring everything in place (i.e. without reinstalling Linux from scratch, and then copying the unencrypted home dir in its place)?

Really unexpected that this happened. I don't know which of the updates messed things up. The packages that were updated are:
`firefox-locale-en:amd64 (96.0.2+linuxmint1+una, 96.0.3+linuxmint1+una), firefox-locale-nl:amd64 (96.0.2+linuxmint1+una, 96.0.3+linuxmint1+una), libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (2.34.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 2.34.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 (2.34.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 2.34.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), firefox:amd64 (96.0.2+linuxmint1+una, 96.0.3+linuxmint1+una), libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 (2.34.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 2.34.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 (2.34.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 2.34.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1`

Only other thing that I can think of was that I had just installed two different CUDA versions before the reboot (but those were in `/usr/local` anyway).

Edit: rechecked `/var/log/apt/history.log` and found that separately before that (about an hour earlier), I had installed `cmake` (with `apt`). What was installed was the following: `Install: librhash0:amd64 (1.3.9-1, automatic), cmake-data:amd64 (3.16.3-1ubuntu1, automatic), cmake:amd64 (3.16.3-1ubuntu1)`. I don't recall doing any reboot between installing cmake and running the other updates. Could the installation of librhash be the reason things broke?

Edit2: restored a Timeshift snapshot from before the issues, hoping that some of the software I'd installed was causing the issue. No luck.

Comment: Seemingly none of these packages could have caused this issue. CUDA also doesn't strike as a candidate. I presume it's something else only I've no clues.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Might be librhash0? Check the edit I made to the post.

Comment: At least in Fedora 35 librhash is **not** necessary for LUKS volumes encryption. I don't have it installed while I use luks encryption. Yes, CMAKE needs it, correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying to diagnose what happened, the most likely cause would be a bad SSD trim. Or solar rays. Not sure.

Run `journalctl | grep fstrim` to check. This is what I did and I had a weekly trim that happened ~3h before the fateful reboot.

For others who might come across this, boot from live USB, mount/decrypt your home dir (https://askubuntu.com/a/873171/1113584) and copy your data somewhere safe. Then backup your packages (with `dpkg --get-selections > mylist.list` and `flatpak --list > flatpaklist.list` - because Mint's backup tool doesn't see any packages installed). Don't forget to copy these .list files to a backup too.

At this point ecryptfs is probably borked and not worth fixing.
So what you need to do to restore your system:

1. reinstall Mint (with or without encryption)
2. reinstall all of the programs in the two .list files you just made
3. <s>boot from the live USB you just used to install Mint again, open the backup and the partition you installed Mint to</s> this will mess up permissions so just skip to 4)
4. copy back the /home/ dir you just backed up

If all goes well, you should have your system back as it was before (and a day wasted).

Thanks to lARRYlAFFER and DJPH from #linuxmint-help for the suggestions.